# Invalid literal for int - Getting raw data from CSV file

Tags: python, csv, input, format

I have a CSV file where one of their lines is a list of strings:

```
['1', '2', '3', '4']
```

I read through the file like this:

```
data = sys.argv[1]
with open(data, 'rb') as csvfile:

    query = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', skipinitialspace=True)

    for row in range(23):
            if row == 1:
            date = next(query)
        elif row == 11:
            cores = next(query) # Problem in this line
        elif row == 13:
            time_interval = next(query)
        elif row == 17:
            number_cores = next(query)
        else:
            next(query)
```

But when I do this, I don't get the exact line. Instead I get:

```
["['1'", "'2'", "'3'", "'4']"]
```

This way, I have the problem that I can not convert each element into an int with map for example.

I get the following error:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 2['1'"
```

I supposed I need to get rid of the quotation marks "" and the first and last [] symbol. I have been trying, but with no success.

Hope I have explained myself correctly.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have an error on line 17... Just kidding. We can't debug this without a [mcve].

Comment: Ok, Will complete the code in just a second, Sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your CSV parser is (correctly) treating the square brackets and single quotes as part of the fields. The line you shared is a valid CSV line, but not in the way you want. The line you want is:

```
1,2,3,4
```

Note that there are no square brackets, and no quotes. For this row, your CSV parser would probably return the list:

```
['1', '2', '3', '4']
```

If you are unable to change the format of your input CSV, I would recommend not using a CSV parser.

Just to emphasize: the problem is likely in how the CSV is being created, not in how you are reading it.